# After power on Rpi3 RED led steady but green continuously blinking. what could be the problem?

Tags: boot, hdmi, ethernet, led

i brought new Rpi3 and boot 16gb card with 2017-03-02-raspbian-jessie when power on red led steady and green blinking is there any problem in booting process of pi? HDMI not showing anything neither lan cable find IP address what will be the solution.

Comment: The LED is possibly blinking in a pattern, e.g., 4 blinks at 2 Hz, 1 second pause, repeat.  This would indicate a specific problem with the SD card.

Comment: Ditto.  Try it with a different SD card.  Perhaps download NOOBS yourself:  https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/